# Why is LinearLayout touch animation occurring on wrong element?

Tags: java, android, touch, android-linearlayout

I have an Android Fragment consisting of nested LinearLayouts. The bottom of the screen consists of 4 LinearLayouts that act as buttons (class_btn_1, class_btn_2, class_btn_3, and class_btn_4). The program is Android/Java. Everything works in the code as expected. But, the system's touch animation for any of the "buttons" always appears on the 4th button, regardless of which of the 4 buttons are tapped. Anyone know why that may be?

Config info:

```
        minSdkVersion 27 // API version for Moto G5 is 27
        targetSdkVersion 31
```

Versions of dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
```

Xml for the Fragment definition. The buttons are near the bottom of the definition.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
      android:focusable="false"
      tools:context="com.google.learning.brain.mobile.transfer.android.MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/classes_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/classes_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sharpness"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ValueNotSet"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/className"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/unclassified"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/classImageStats"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classImageStats"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/ValueNotSet"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/className"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logDateEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/StringValueNotSet"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logClassName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/StringValueNotSet"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/modeSpinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:entries="@array/train_mode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/deleteImgButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/classImageStats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteImgButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/delete_image_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/preparedImagePreview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/classImageStats" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/classes_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/classes_bar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/class_btn_1"
          style="@style/ClassButton"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_weight=".25"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="4dp"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/class_btn_2"
          style="@style/ClassButton"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_weight=".25"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="4dp"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/classes_bar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/class_btn_3"
          style="@style/ClassButton"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_weight=".25"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="4dp"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/class_btn_4"
          style="@style/ClassButton"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_weight=".25"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="4dp"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLabel43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:tag="subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainInstruction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/classes_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

I'm hoping someone can make sense of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this appears to be a clash between material design and older UI design support functions in Android. The main fix for my issue was to REMOVE the style setting from the button definitions:

```
style="@style/ClassButton"
```

The other change that allowed retaining the "ripple" touch animation was to change the button background:

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_default_ripple"
```

where btn_default_ripple.xml is a drawable that wraps a typical button background drawable within the ripple tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_bg" />
</ripple>
```

I forgot to mention the dependency for material being used, it was:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

These changes seem to have eliminated the odd touch animations.